# Two lists on different sides of the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header, with a few items in it: links to navigate the page, and links to log in/sign up. I'm doing this with two separate lists. It looks like this:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#header #title {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header.menu li {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>webpage title</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="header menu" id="header-menu-1">
    <li>about</li>
    <li>pricing</li>
    <li>contact</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="header menu" id="header-menu-2">
    <li>log in</li>
    <li>sign up</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, all the items are aligned to the left. I've tried using:

```
.header.menu #header-menu-1 ul {
  float: left;
}

.header.menu #header-menu-2 ul {
  float: right;
}
```

but there is no effect.

How can I separate them - one on the left and one on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong, there should be no space and the ul is not a child. Also it's good practice to specify id first, then class:

```
ul#header-menu-1.header.menu {
  float: left;
}

ul#header-menu-2.header.menu {
  float: right;
}
```

Realistically you only need the id though:

```
#header-menu-1 {
  float: left;
}

#header-menu-2 {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: This is still wrong.  EDIT: You fixed the error, but these selectors are overly specific. Once you've included an ID in a selector, anything else (like tags or classes) are pointless unless you're applying a modifier.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't noticed he had UL in there as well as id.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selectors were written wrong.

`#header-menu-1 ul` is going to select a `<ul>` element inside (a child of)  an element with the ID `#header-menu-1`.

Instead, you can simply use `#header-menu-1` as your selector since an ID is as specific as you can be.

In the future, if you want to combine a tag and a class, you can do it like so: `ul.classname`.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#title {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header.menu li {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#header-menu-1 {
  float: left;
}

#header-menu-2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>webpage title</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="header menu" id="header-menu-1">
    <li>about</li>
    <li>pricing</li>
    <li>contact</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="header menu" id="header-menu-2">
    <li>log in</li>
    <li>sign up</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Remove space between `.menu` and `#header-menu-1`(and `#header-menu-2`).

2)Remove `ul` from last of selectors.

**Change:**

```
.header.menu #header-menu-1 ul {
  float: left;
}

.header.menu #header-menu-2 ul {
  float: right;
}
```

**To:**

```
.header.menu#header-menu-1 {
  float: left;
}

.header.menu#header-menu-2{
  float: right;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#header #title {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header.menu li {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header.menu#header-menu-1 {
  float: left;
}

.header.menu#header-menu-2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>webpage title</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="header menu" id="header-menu-1">
    <li>about</li>
    <li>pricing</li>
    <li>contact</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="header menu" id="header-menu-2">
    <li>log in</li>
    <li>sign up</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you give me downvote for no reason?where is wrong in my answer?